# xPath help > Find img with alt='My Keyword'

Tags: xpath, domdocument

How can I alter this xpath to find if the content contains an img tag with an alt containing my keyword phrase?

$xPath->evaluate('count(/html/body//'.$tag.'[contains(.,"'.$keyword.'")])');

Comment: @Scott-B: Please, edit your question and put your comment to @Gaim at the start of the text. Otherwise it makes little sense and doesn't contain a question at all

Comment: @Scott-B: Although your question is quite vague, see some possible solutions in my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Use**:

```
boolean(//img[contains(@alt, 'yourKeywordHere')])
```

to find (`true()`, `false()`) whether there is an `img` element in the XML document whose `alt` attribute contains `'yourKeywordHere'`.

**Use**:

```
boolean(//yourTag//img[contains(@alt, 'yourKeywordHere')])
```

to find if there is an element in the document named `yourTag` that has a descendent `img` whose `alt` attribute contains `'yourKeywordHere'`.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. That makes perfect sense. Could I use xpath to determine if the keyword appears in the first and/or last sentence of the document? I'm thinking xpath would not recognize a "sentence" as an entity like a node.

Comment: @Scott-B: You need to define "sentence" precisely.

Comment: I don't see difference between my and your answer except 4 hours but never mind

Comment: @Gaim: Your answer selects all `h1` elements that have a descendent `img` element whose `alt` attribute contains some specific string. Instead, what @Scott-B wants is to know just one bit of information -- `true()` or `false()` -- "*Is* there such an element". This is what I give him with my answer.

Comment: @Scott-B: If by "sentence" you mean HTML "block element", then you could test for not preceding "block" elements (first test), or not following "block" element (last test).

Comment: @Scott-B: If by "sentence" you mean string tokenized by new line character, you could test for not preceding text nodes having a new line character or not following text nodes having a new line character.

Comment: I'm referring to a string of text sandwiched between two period characters. I've amended my approach to x characters vs "sentence" and was able to just use substr_count

Comment: @Scott-B: It is best to ask this as a new question. Finding the "last sentence" is a little bit more tricky than the "first sentrnce".

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand exactly what elements you are loooking for, but here is the example, which returns all elements `h1` which contains at least one image with `your_keyword` in alt:

```
//h1[.//img[contains(@alt, 'your_keyword')]]
```

You should also handle if it is case sensitive or not. You can use this xpath but be careful, some xpath evaluators doesn't support `lower-case` function.

```
//h1[.//img[contains(lower-case(@alt), lower-case('your_keyword'))]]
```

Here is example:

```
//h1[.//img[contains(@alt, 'key ')]]

<html>
    <h1> <!-- found -->
        <img alt='here is my key' />
    </h1>
    <h1><!-- not found -->
        <img alt='here is not' />
    </h1>
    <h1> <!-- found -->
        <h2>
            <img alt='the key is also here' />
        </h2>
    </h1>
    <h1></h1> <!-- not found -->

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Gaim, I'm looking to determine if at least one image within the content has an alt containing the keyword. I think I can take your example and go from there. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Scott-B: Please, edit your question and put your comment at the start of the text. Otherwise it makes little sense and doesn't contain a question at all.